# After Install kubectl "-bash: /home/ec2-user/bin/kubectl: Permission denied"

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubectl

I have installed some times in Ec2 Kubectl with the same commands, but actually is not working in the final when I will look if the version is working with the command "kubectl version --short --client" I get back message: "-bash: /home/ec2-user/bin/kubectl: Permission denied"

The process commands that I have used is this :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-kubectl.html

I don't change any code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you `chmod +x ./kubectl`?

If you forgot and `mv`'d the binary, you can apply the execute permission `chmod +x $HOME/bin/kubectl`

Comment: Hello context, the following is wrong, I installed Kubectl with cloud9 with root user where it has the function of "Aws management temporary credentials" and after changing the credentials kubectl does not accept new update.
with the update commands for new credentials, the only way I found restart the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try running,

```
sudo chmod +x /home/ec2-user/bin/kubectl
```

And also make sure that your user has that executable permission for kubectl.